# Subclipse connection to a Sourceforge-project: Authentification?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, sourceforge

I am currently stuck how to set up my project I once have had with the new Eclipse-structure. I have installed Eclipse 4.3 with Subclipse.

I can add a repository like the following:

View SVN Repositories => Add new SVN repository ==> URL:

```
svn://leo_forge@svn.code.sf.net/p/hexlib/code/
```

Then I can checkout the project which is fine. I get everything. BUT I never specified my password nor any credentials. Therefore the commit fails.

Question:

1. What is the proper approach to set up Subclipse properly?
2. Where to specify the login-credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify login credentials.  Subversion has no way to force credentials, the server has to challenge you for them.  I do not use SourceForge, but I would guess they have a different URL for write operations.  svn:// protocol is unencrypted so I doubt they allow commit via that protocol.  Most likely they require https:// or svn+ssh:// protocol to commit changes.  Those protocols probably challenge you.

When Subversion is challenged for credentials, it fires a callback that Subclipse provides that will in turn prompt you in the UI.

Comment: Thx for the detailed workflow which made it more understandable what goes on in the background. Helped!